# Access touchbar from viewController?

Tags: swift, nstouchbar

I´m currently playing around with an app that's creating its own touchbar layout. Only simple buttons with text that shows up.

The thing is that I have a WindowController and a ViewController. The WindowController makes the touchbar with its buttons.

But what I want to do is in the ViewController when I press a button I want the touchbar to change, like if you would update it.

So my question is, how do I from the ViewController get access to the touchbar created in the `windowController`?

The relation is WindowController (creating touchbar, setting 2 default buttons and showing it) -> ViewController (button to change touchbar)

Any ideas? I'm new to Mac development so please call me an idiot and give me a lead :D

Comment: Getting informations from previous controller is quite tricky.
What do you need 2 controllers ? If you need informations from the touchbar you probably need to fusionate your controllers on the same view.

Comment: @AlainBerrier, well if I should be honest, I don't really know. I started a MacOS project and want suggested to create a WindowController for the first View so I then could create a customized touchbar. The WindowController view don't allow me to add any buttons to it if its not a ViewController (right?). So my though was to but a button in the new ViewController that when pressed modify the original created TouchBar created by the WindowController.

Comment: Each viewController controls a view and do the actions you told him to do.
You can call an other controller on your controller with the storyboard or programmatically but **accessing the variables of the previous controller is not the right think to do (and I think it's impossible).**
You should create only one controller with a button that directly change the toucher

Comment: Please explain what is your intent, your goal. I'm rather sure you actually don't need two controllers just in order to achieve something with the touch bar.